# spring jpa join two entities

Tags: spring, jpa, entity

I'm struggling to join two entity models using jpa crudRepository interface. i can't figure out how to map two entity model and write query inside @Query annotation. these are my entity classes. 
I want to execute this query "SELECT dppd.payment_plan_id,dppd.attribute_value,dppd.attribute_id FROM taxi_driver_mapping AS tdm JOIN driver_payment_plan_details AS dppd on dppd.payment_plan"

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "driver_payment_plan_details")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DriverPaymentPlanDetails
{
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private int id ;

@Column(name = "payment_plan_id")
private long paymentPlanId;

@Column(name = "attribute_id")
private int attributeId;

@Column(name = "attribute_value")
private float attributeValue;
```

}

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Table(name = "taxi_driver_mapping")
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TaxiDriverMapping
{
@Column(name = "mapping_id")
@Id
private Long mappingId;

@Column(name = "mapping_driverid")
private Long mappingDriverId;

@Column(name = "mapping_taxi_model_id")
private String mappingTaxiModelId;

@Column(name = "mapping_status")
private String mappingStatus;

@Column(name = "mapping_payment_plan_id")
private Long mappingPaymentPlanId;
```

}

Comment: You can't join entities if they don't have any association. Read a tutorial, a book, or the Hibernate documentation about JPA, and learn about associations. They're a funcamental part of JPA, that you need to understand. Every time you have the ID of another entity in an entity, you're doing something wrong. Then, once you understand associations, read the documentation of JPQL.

Comment: and "JPA" has no XXXRepository. That is "Spring Data JPA", which is not the JPA API.

Comment: @JBNizet that's not true: https://72.services/how-to-join-two-entities-without-mapped-relationship/

Comment: OK, you can. Should you? The whole point of JPA is to have a graph of entities and to be able to navigate through that graph. Having only isolated entities with IDs everywhere is not how JPA is meant to be used, makes things harder than necessary, and show a lack of understanding.

Comment: I agree with @JBNizet, you shouldn't use it this way and please consider linking them in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for showing a correct path, this is my code.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Table(name = "taxi_driver_mapping")
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TaxiDriverMapping
{
@Column(name = "mapping_id")
@Id
private Long mappingId;

@Column(name = "mapping_driverid")
private Long mappingDriverId;

@Column(name = "mapping_taxi_model_id")
private String mappingTaxiModelId;

@Column(name = "mapping_status")
private String mappingStatus;

@Column(name = "mapping_payment_plan_id")
private Long mappingPaymentPlanId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "taxiDriverMapping")
private List<DriverPaymentPlanDetails> driverPaymentPlanDetails;
```

}

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @Entity
 @ToString
 @Table(name = "driver_payment_plan_details")
 @NoArgsConstructor
 public class DriverPaymentPlanDetails
 {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private int id ;

@Column(name = "payment_plan_id")
private long paymentPlanId;

@Column(name = "attribute_id")
private int attributeId;

@Column(name = "attribute_value")
private float attributeValue;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="payment_plan_id",insertable = false,updatable = false)
private TaxiDriverMapping taxiDriverMapping;

}
```